# CookSwing - Retrieving the string from a textfield

Tags: java, swing

I'm using CookSwing (http://cookxml.yuanheng.org/cookswing/) to build a Java Swing UI, but the site doesn't have a lot of information.  I'm stuck trying to get my Java class to retrieve the string from a textfield in the form (declared in XML).  This should be easy to do, but nothing I've tried works.  Does anyone have experience doing this?  Here is the Java class:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import cookxml.cookswing.CookSwing;

public final class CookSwingForm
{
  // Listener for the Quit button
  public ActionListener exitAction = new ActionListener()
  {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
    {
      System.exit(0);
    }
  };

  public CookSwingForm()
  {
    CookSwing cookSwing = new CookSwing(this);
    cookSwing.render("sampleform.xml").setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    new CookSwingForm();
  }
}
```

Here is the XML file ("sampleform.xml"):

```
<frame title="Sample Form" size="300,70"
       defaultcloseoperation="EXIT_ON_CLOSE">
  <borderlayout>
    <constraint location="West">
       <textfield columns="20" />
    </constraint>
    <constraint location="East">
      <button text="Quit" actionlistener="exitAction" />
    </constraint>
  </borderlayout>
</frame>
```

I just need to have the Java class retrieve the string from the textfield that's declared in the XML file.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use the `id` attribute and then use that as the variable name for the text field.

The xml would look as : `<textfield id="box1" />`

Here is what you have to do:

```
JTextField txtField = (JTextField) cookSwing.getId("box1").object;
//now,set some text 
txtField.setText("Blah!");
//or get some text as you may wish
```

Also. Looks like the library is no longer being developed. That's a red flag right there.

Comment: Yes, I can give the textfield an ID or a name in the XML file, but how would I use that to refer to the textfield from the Java class?